# AspxGridView: How to Convert Date Column Value to Date.ToShortDateString()?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using an editing control for ASPxGridView. It all works fine so far, but I have only one problem. From normal DatePicker, I can send the date value without time by ASPxDateEdit.Date.ToShortDateString().

But When I want to do it with the column in my ASPxGrid, the e.NewValues["dateColumn"].ToShortDateString() doesn't work. There is only ToString after dot.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `e.NewValues["dateColumn"]` isn't typed, it's unaware that the value is actually a `DateTime`, so `ToShortDateString` isn't available.

You can cast it to `DateTime`, and then the option will be available for you

```
((DateTime)e.NewValues["dateColumn"]).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: *shame being a newbie* Thank you!

Comment: Argh... "Cannot unbox 'e.NewValues["dateColumn"]' as a 'System.DateTime'" error

Comment: @confeng: Ah, ok.  Can you try `DateTime.Parse(e.NewValues["dateColumn"])`.  I don't currently have a web forms app in front of me otherwise I'd test it out myself.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: @ataddeini: Well the code runned with a little bit modify, but it didn't work, there's still "06.05.2011 00:00:00" value in the database.
That's the code I modified to:
DateTime.Parse(e.NewValues["dateColumn"].ToString()).ToString();
I guess I was wrong NOT to inform that my date column is NVARCHAR in the db.

Comment: @confeng: OK, well glad it's casting at least.  I see you're still using `ToString()` instead of `ToShortDateString()`.  The latter should be available after the `DateTime.Parse`.  As an alternative you can pass in a format string like this: `ToString("M/d/yyyy")`

Comment: Ouch, missed that ToShortDateString(). When I replaced, it worked. Like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hate that. It changes existing values but when I try to add a date unexisting, here is the new error:
'DateTime.Parse(e.NewValues["dateColumn"].ToString())' threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'

Comment: Sometimes we need to try easiest way I guess. Final solution of my problem is: e.NewValues["columnDate"].ToString().Substring(0, 10); //Thanks for support.

Comment: @confeng: Gald you were able to get it to work.  For the `System.FormatException` you could also consider using [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx).  It will try to convert the string to a `DateTime` and if it can't, it will return `null` instead of throwing the exceptions.